# Восстановление полного бэкапа Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, администрирование, резервное-копирование, vmware, виртуальная-машина

Всем привет.

Есть бэкап Windows Server 2016,снятый через Windows Server Backup. Бэкап полный,т.е. все разделы присутствуют.

Как можно полностью восстановить этот бэкап на другую машину? Пробовал устанавливать на другую машину WS2016,и через Windows Server Backup восстанавливать System State,но программы,а именно SCCM не восстанавливаются таким образом.

Можно ли как-то эти образа воспроизвести через VMBox,или подобные программы? Т.к. по сути нужно только слить программы из меню SCCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так: создал на другом компе разделы размером 400mb и 70gb,и восстановил на них через wbadmin свои бекапы. Затем выполнил bootrec /rebuild-bcd,и после через среду WinRE сделал StartUP Repair